# Why do I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am practicing some algorithm problems. While I use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get some input, my program throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` in thread "main", and I really don't know why. It can compile on my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and the outcome is right, but when I submit code on OJ web, it throws the aforementioned exception.

The stack trace with the error message of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.ScannerthrowFor(Scannerjava:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scannernext(Scannerjava:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scannernextlnt(Scannerjava:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.ScannernextInt(Scannerjava:2212)
 at Main.main(Main.java:11)

non-zero return = 1
```

[screenshot of my class in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c8Pt.png)

[screenshot of the stack trace in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvY7x.png)

My Main class:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int[] nums;
    static int[] b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        nums = new int[n];
        b = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
            b[i] = nums[i + 1] - nums[i];
        Arrays.sort(b,0,n - 1);

        int d = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n - 2; ++j){
            d = gcd(b[j],b[j + 1]);
            b[j + 1] = d;
        }

        int ans = (nums[n - 1] - nums[0]) / d + 1;
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    static int gcd(int a,int b){
        return b == 0? a: gcd(b,a % b);
    }
}
```

I try to read the source code, but I cannot understand fully the source code. I tried to search for a solution on the web, but I did not find anything about my problem. I would like to know why it throws this exception, and how to fix it to avoid such anomalies.

Comment: You're trying to read tokens from `System.in` but if you read the JavaDoc you'll see that `NoSuchElementException` is thrown when there are no tokens, i.e. when the input stream is closed. When you're running the application locally that stream would be kept open waiting for your input. When uploading this the application would be executed without user intervention so they're probably testing it with an empty or too short input stream. Fix this by handling this situation, e.g. catching the exception and reacting accordingly.

Comment: This question is answered [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--): 'thrown when the input is exhausted'. However the problem is really in your code: you should not call `nextInt()` without having previously got `true` from `hasNextInt()`, and if you got `false` you should have printed an error message. Which would have answered your question for you.

Comment: maybe not the problem, I do not know the working of that website, but I would recommend to NOT close the `Scanner` - it will also close `System.in` and your code did not open it, so it should not close it || also unknown: format of data input - by posted code it should be: <n:number of elements> <element 1> <element 2> ... <element n>

Comment: "But when I submit code on OJ web, it throws the aforementioned Exception." It appears they don't offer you a System.in that you can use with your scanner. Do they perhaps give you the data as an argument to main?